# IBM Lotus Notes SIGNING XPAGES DOCUMENT in WEB browser

Tags: web, xpages, lotus-notes, signing

First of all. I am a beginner in IBM development and i don't have a lot of experience in IBM Domino server or Xpages.

My task is like this:
"Create a document using xpages, and sign document using ID from server ID Vault and get Verified by server".

I have a simple form consisting of two inputs (subject, content).  I have Xpages page and everything set up for creating and viewing documents.
But i got stuck trying to sign each document with user id. I have set up user ID in Vault. Then I enter X-page from browser (not Notes Client) i have access to forms and documents.. with configured credentials.

So basically what I'm asking is:

**HOW TO SIGN DOCUMENTS from web browser (X-pages) using ID from Vault and get Verified by Server ?**

Answer (score 2):

The most practical answer to this, I believe, is to wait for a future Feature Pack to 9.0.1. API access to ID Vault names (including this ability specifically) is one of the features that was in the 9.0.2 stream but which is now (presumably) broken out into an upcoming feature pack.

As for *which* feature pack, I can't quite say: I see it on the list of planned features, but not on the table of which release/date it is slotted for currently. I wouldn't be surprised if it came alongside Verse-on-premises, but that's mere speculation.

Comment: Maybe in the future it's gonna by a lot easier. 

But right now I know it's possible but i don't know exactly how.

Comment: How do you know it's possible? I admit that I haven't been paying close attention to this  lately, but I was watching and waiting for programmatic access to ID Vault for signing and encryption purposes for years.

Comment: I done some research and I found that that it's should be possible through the server connecting to the API